# I have to make a java program to list directory from input

Tags: java, list, directory

I dont really know how to express my words but here's the output example.

> Please enter the desired folder: c:/Test
>
> a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
>
> Enter the name of the file that you want to run: a.txt
>
> Hello Java!

And if I put the file with nothing in it, the output will be

> The file is empty. Start again.

Comment: You should post the code what have you tried if you expect help from others.

Answer (score 1):

You are so lazy to google the basics.
I'll help you:
1. Get directory content:[How to get contents of a folder and put into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301764/how-to-get-contents-of-a-folder-and-put-into-an-arraylist)
2. Output file content: [How do you read a text file and print it to the console window? Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307026/how-do-you-read-a-text-file-and-print-it-to-the-console-window-java) and [How to write console output to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file)

Consider googling an 'if-else' situations.
Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to take console input and read ONLY txt files, you can try the following

**Read Contents from  File (if present)**

```
public static void main(String... s)throws IOException {
    String folderName = "C://Test//";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    File file = new File(folderName+fileName);
    if(file.exists() && file.isFile() && file.length() > 0) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("This file is empty. Start again");
    }

}
```

**Display hello java if file is found**

```
public static void main(String... s)throws IOException {
    String folderName = "C://Test//";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    File file = new File(folderName+fileName);
    if(file.exists() && file.isFile() && file.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java!");          
    } else {
        System.out.println("This file is empty. Start again");
    }

}
```

*The program will run, and you can input your desired filename (with .txt extension)*